# How to update values in mongoDB using Express.js and axios

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I want to be able to update a specific posts data inside my mongoDB using the object id. I have already created a html form where the fields get populated with the selected post data. I can then change these values and submit the form data to http://localhost:5000/update-opportunity. In my backend I then wait for a form submission on this url. This where I am stuck I don't know how to use the id I sent with axios to update a specific object in the database.

Heres my code;

axois form submission in vue component

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/update-opportunity', {
    id: this.id,
    company_name: this.company_name,
    company_type: this.company_type,
    lines_of_business: this.lines_of_business,
    client_type: this.client_type,
    contract_type: this.contract_type,
    contact_name: this.contact_name,
    contact_number: this.contact_number,
    email_address: this.email_address,
    opportunity_owner: this.opportunity_owner,
    decision_maker: this.decision_maker,
    annual_jobs: this.annual_jobs,
    average_fee: this.average_fee,
    annual_value: this.annual_value,
    next_steps: this.next_steps,
    due_date: this.due_date
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.$emit('formSubmitted');
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

backend form submission

```
router.post('/update-opportunity', (req, res, next) => {
    const db = getDb();
    db
        .collection('jobs')
        .insertOne({
            company_name: req.body.company_name,
            company_type: req.body.company_type,
            lines_of_business: req.body.lines_of_business,
            client_type: req.body.client_type,
            contract_type: req.body.contract_type,
            contact_name: req.body.contact_name,
            contact_number: req.body.contact_number,
            email_address: req.body.email_address,
            opportunity_owner: req.body.opportunity_owner,
            decision_maker: req.body.decision_maker,
            annual_jobs: req.body.annual_jobs,
            average_fee: req.body.average_fee,
            annual_value: req.body.annual_value,
            next_steps: req.body.next_steps,
            due_date: req.body.due_date,
            date_added: new Date()
        })
        .then(result => {
            res.status(201).send();
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

getDb() is just my database connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use "update" method in mongo.

Currently trying to add a record.

Try something like this

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb).ObjectID;

db.collection('jobs').update(
{"_id" : req.body.id},
{$set: {
company_name: new ObjectID(req.body.company_name),
            company_type: req.body.company_type,
            lines_of_business: req.body.lines_of_business,
            client_type: req.body.client_type,
            contract_type: req.body.contract_type,
            contact_name: req.body.contact_name,
            contact_number: req.body.contact_number,
            email_address: req.body.email_address,
            opportunity_owner: req.body.opportunity_owner,
            decision_maker: req.body.decision_maker,
            annual_jobs: req.body.annual_jobs,
            average_fee: req.body.average_fee,
            annual_value: req.body.annual_value,
            next_steps: req.body.next_steps,
            due_date: req.body.due_date,
            date_added: new Date()
}});
```

Comment: I think you've got the correct solution here but something isn't working. Is it that I have to convert req.body.id to an objectid?

Comment: Possibly, you might want to check network tab in CHROME, and make sure you are sending data correctly. Also you can try testing your API with POSTMAN

Comment: Yeah it was the ObjectID. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution if you are at the beginning of your project, you could just use à quick start :
https://github.com/greathappyforest/Express-Vue-QuickStart

Comment: This didn't solve my problem but it is a great resource thanks